# Help Code Coverage - Class Implements

Tags: trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I create multiple (x5) classes in my Trigger like this :

```
class TypeHandler_XX implements TypeHandler {
public void action(Task record) {
             /* Block code */
        }
}
```

In the code that I am testing the value of my RecordType and I call the appropriate class.

My problem is this : How can I test the other class, in my ClassTest.
Code coverage = 67%

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert your test records in your test code you need to assign the appropriate Record Type to the record. I assume it's working presently due to the default Record Type being assigned. You can discover the Id's of the Record Types for an object using [Apex Describe](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_instance_methods.htm) then assign the Id to the [RecordTypeId](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) field (see the section below this [topic](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_recordtype.htm) for further discussion).

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypesByName = accountDescribe.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

Account newAccount = new Account();
newAccount.RecordTypeId = recordTypesByName.get('Record Type X1').getRecordTypeId();
```

Comment: I made ​​the recovery of the value of RecordType in my Trigger and not in the class test.
But your answer helped me a lot, I learned more about the Apex language.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I did it ! Code Coverage 100%. Thank you again

Comment: Excellent always a good feeling! Of course you have lots of asserts as well! ;-)